# tap coordinates relative to component

Tags: react-native

I'm struggling with getting relative coordinates when `onPress` is triggered.
Here's a minimal example:

```
import { View, Text, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <Pressable
      onPress={(e) => {
        const pressable = e.currentTarget
        const x = e.nativeEvent.locationX
        const y = e.nativeEvent.locationY
        console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`)
      }}
      style={{ flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{ width: 200, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    </Pressable>
  )
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App
```

So, if I tap outside the yellow box, I get proper coordinates, and those coordinates are relative to the `Pressable` component.
On the contrary, by tapping within the nested `View` (the yellow box), coordinates are relative to the yellow box itself.... and I'd like coordinates being relative to the outer `Pressable`.
The documentation for `locationX` states "*The X position of the touch, relative to the element*", so there's something I cannot sort out.
Any hint, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use [pageX](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressevent#pagex) and [pageY](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressevent#pagey) instead.

> Touch origin X/Y coordinate on the screen (relative to the root view).

```
const x = e.nativeEvent.pageX
const y = e.nativeEvent.pageY
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I've asked. I want to avoid getting screen coordinates and transform those coordinates. I was aware of `pageX` and `pageY`, but it simply doesn't fit with my question.